# AngularJS error "ReferenceError: route is not defined"

Tags: angularjs

Thanks in advance, I am new to AngularJS and don't know what I am missing in below snippet it gives me an error "ReferenceError: route is not defined"

```
app.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider', function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
$urlRouterProvider.
    when('/customers/*/edit',
    route.resolve('CustomerCtrl', 'customer/js/insurance-customer.js'))
    .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/customers/*/edit' });
  }]);
```

It gives an error on this line  **route.resolve** “ReferenceError: route is not defined”

Comment: Inject `routeProvider` in your config. The docs for more info https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/provider/$routeProvider   I gues you are confused with `stateProvider` and `routeProvider` both are different.

Comment: But I am using $urlRouterProvider